# Prevent inline block from wrapping but allow content to wrap

Tags: css, whitespace

I have this layout:

```
<ul style="white-space:nowrap;">
    <li style="width:200px; display:inline-block;"></li>
    <li style="display:inline-block; vertical-align:top; padding-left:10px;"></li>
</ul>
```

I have managed to stop the `ul` from wrapping which is a start. However, the content in the 2nd `li` continues off screen. Overlapping its parent elements etc.

I need the 2nd `li` to take up the slack and be dynamic in width unlike the first `li`. And I need the text to wrap inside the 2nd `li`.

Comment: Do you only need to disable wrapping for the first list item? You could just set `white-space: nowrap;` for it, and not the list container in whole.

Comment: There is an image in the first list item and text in the second. So I'm only concerned about the 2nd list item wrapping.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
li {display:table;}
```

is your friend. Also, don't forget to remove inline-styles!

Comment: Could you please provide an example?

Answer (score 6):

Try `white-space: normal` on the `li` elements.

`white-space` is inherited by default so they received `nowrap` from the `ul`.

I'm starting to think that you are using an `ul` for layout purposes which `div` might be better suited for:

```
<div class="Item">
 <div class="ImageContainer"><img src="" alt="/></div>
 <div class="TextContainer">Text text text text text</div>
</div>

.Item {
 width: 200px;
 overflow: auto;
}

.ImageContainer {
 float: left;
 width: 40%;
}

.TextContainer {
 float: left;
 width: 60%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks - it seems to only work for me this, if I add a fixed width as well. I don't really want to add a width to the 2nd li.

Comment: Can you specifiy what you want then? Because I'm starting to think you might be using the `ul` for layout purposes rather than to make a list. And if so then perhaps some floating `div`s might do the job better.

Comment: First li holds an image the second li should hold wrapable text. The second li can grow and shrink in size dependant on screen resolution.

Comment: That sounds like a div with a background image and left padding to me. Consider this: `<div id="x">text text text</div>` and `#x {padding-left: 200px; background-image: url(myimage.jpg);}`

Comment: @Bazzz No, it's not a background image. It's a foreground image. Making it a background image may appear correct, but that's a hack and semantically incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you might actually want to use a table.

Otherwise, if you know the width of the image, float it left and give the next element a left margin greater than or equal to the width of the image.

For example:

```css
article > img {
  float: left;
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
}
article > div {
  margin-left: 90px;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/7e6e0e2b73358e47e0b7f83f8111f75b">
  <div>
    <h4>Matt Di Pasquale</h3>
    <p>I know the width of the image is 80px, so I floated it left and gave the <code>div</code> a 90px left margin. That way, everything gets layed out perfectly, and this paragraph's text wraps.</p>
  </div>
</article>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a practical use case for [CSS Grid Layout](https://devdocs.io/css/css_grid_layout):

```css
ul {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 200px 1fr;
  column-gap: 10px;
}
li {
  display: unset; /* reset user agent list-style */
}
img {
  background: #00bcd4; /* style image background */
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li><img width="200" src="data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%20/%3E%0A">
<li>long text content next to the image long text content next to the image long text content next to the image long text content next to the image
</ul>
```

Creates two-column grid with `10px` column gap. First grid item has `200px` width to match your image and the second wrapping text.

If if content you're trying to wrap may contain long strings such as an absolute URL or scientific/medical terms like pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis add [`overflow-wrap`](https://devdocs.io/css/overflow-wrap) to the second `li` using the [`:last-of-type`](https://devdocs.io/css/:last-of-type) pseudo-class.